# Unable to install nuget packages in xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am facing a very strange issue regarding installing NuGet packages in the xamarin android project. When I try to install any NuGet package in xamarin android project getting an error.

Here is the error message I am getting from the NuGet package manager.

```
?Restoring packages for E:\Projects\Sample\Sample1\Sample2\Smaple3\SampleApp.Android\SampleApp.Android.csproj...
NU1202: Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell 1.1.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell 1.1.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
NU1202: Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Core 1.1.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Core 1.1.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'SampleApp.Android'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.9192186
========== Finished ==========
```

[image]

Installed packages in the Android project:

[image]

Comment: This package is not compatible with mono.android you can't use it

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have tried to update xamarin.forms version at that time also getting above error. It's very annoying to me.

Comment: Why do you even need the APICodePack anyways?

Comment: I have doesn't install that package in android project. it' installed in pcl project only.

Comment: As per the error it should be in your android project take a look

Comment: I have checked in references in the android project but I have doesn't any reference regarding this package. Anyway, I will check one more time. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Hi, I have checked in my android project. In my android project windows, api code pack is not installed.

Comment: Ok paste the error code as text here, do not post image i need to see the full error

Comment: I have updated question with error code. Can you please look at once.

Comment: check android references directly in project not from here Check `App>Reference`

Comment: Hi, Finally I have found the cause of packages is not installed In my android project. In my android project, I have reference pcl project. In my pcl project windows api code pack shell nuget is installed that is the reason of packages are failed to installed in the android project. Once I remove pcl reference from my android project, packages are successfully installed without compatibility issue.

Comment: I have posted an answer take a look, but if you removed your pcl from Android project then how will you use xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack` from your PCL, since you are having a reference of it in the PCL and then your Android project refers the PCL that works like an indirect reference hence it is causing the issue.

Solution: remove the package from PCL project